# Do JDBC connection hold hard references to their PreparedStatement s?

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g, garbage-collection

I want to cache prepared statements that I build. When the connection they are built on is CG'd, I'd like to forget about the prepared statements.

I'd like to make a WeakHashMap of connection->statement, but this won't work. Statements hold hard references to their connection objects, and so the connection will never be GC'd.

So I could hold a WeakHashMap of connection objects to weak references to the prepared statements for each connection. But if the connection object does not hold a hard reference to the statements, then the statements will get GC'd. On the other hand, if it does then everything is sweet.

Do we know if it does?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. First, behaviour is not defined. Second, the answer is no - the prepared statements are GC'd unless you hold a hard reference to them.

I think that what I am attempting to do may actually be impossible with java references and the fact that my code does not create the connection and prepared statement objects.

Oh well. I'll just crate new PreparedStatements when I need 'em and release them after use.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle will cache connections and statements for you. There is unlikely to be any real value in trying to develop your own cache.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/stmtcach.htm#JJDBC28649